# Kubernetes pod went down

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am pretty new to Kubernetes so I don't have much idea. Last day a pod went down and I was thinking if I would be able to recover the tmp folder.

So basically I want to know that when a pod in Kubernetes goes down, does it lose access to the "/tmp" folder ?

Comment: why do you think it has access to /tmp(or any) folder when it's up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you configure otherwise, this folder will be considered storage within the container, and the contents will be lost when the container terminates.

Similarly to how you can run a container in docker, write something to the filesystem within the container, then stop and remove the container, start a new one, and find the file you wrote within the container is no longer there.

If you want to keep the `/tmp` folder contents between restarts, you'll need to attach a [persistent volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes) to it and mount it as `/tmp` within the container, but with the caveat that if you do that, you cannot use that same volume with other replicas in a deployment unless you use a read-write-many capable filesystem underneath, like NFS.